# What's the difference between Shared Worker and Worker in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

After reading this blog post: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-shared-web-workers-html5/

I don't get it. What's the difference between a `Worker` and a `SharedWorker`?

Comment: Might be worth checking out http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/workers.html#shared-workers-introduction

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Very basic distinction: a `Worker` can only be accessed from the script that created it, a `SharedWorker` can be accessed by any script that comes from the same domain.

Comment: Umm, so `SharedWorker` on a popup via `window.open` can access others assuming they are on the same origin? What if they are on an entirely new tab, I guess no?

Comment: @Tower "Same origin" has nothing to do with the page that spawned another page. It means (roughly) the domain name from where the script was called. See [this chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript#Definition_of_an_origin) . So two scripts, both on `example.com`, can access the same `SharedWorker` even across different tabs.

Comment: So, does that mean a regular WebWorker can only have one connection even if the user duplicates their tab running the same script from the same domain? Or is that still considered the same script by the browser? In other words, app.js connects to worker.js, then the user replicates their tab: can tab2 still connect to worker.js? Will worker.js still maintain the same memory pool between tab1's app.js and tab2's app.js. I'm interested because I need to maintain a Queue structure in a background-process / daemon and post events to such daemon from any open tab within the same application.

Answer (score 17):

To anyone considering using SharedWorker -- Apple removed support of `SharedWorker` from WebKit in 2015. In their [current roadmap](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140344) there is no plan for reimplementation. Support for [Service Workers](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/) is currently under development for WebKit and offer similar capabilities ([see here for comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909021/3508192)).

You can follow the development (aka Safari support) of [ServiceWorkers in WebKit here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174541).

Comment: What does this mean? Apple is not supporting sharedworkers?

Comment: It means that Apple WebKit removed support of SharedWorkers as of [Changeset 178310](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/178310/webkit) and does not plan on reintroducing their support.

Comment: what? does Apple want to become the new internet explorer?

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias Apple/Safari has been the new Internet Explorer for quite some time now. :)

Comment: Great point! Here is a link that shows the (poor) support for `SharedWorker` https://caniuse.com/sharedworkers

Comment: As of 2022, SharedWorker is back on the roadmap and looks to already be implemented in Safari 16 TP - https://webkit.org/status/#feature-shared-web-workers

Answer (score 13):

SharedWorker's seem to have more functionality then Worker.

Among that functionality is :

- A shared global scope. All `SharedWorker` instances share a single global scope.

W3C Spec:

- [SharedWorker](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#sharedworker)
- [Worker](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#worker)

WHATWG Spec:

- [SharedWorker](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/workers.html#sharedworker)
- [Worker](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/workers.html#worker)

Comment: Does SharedWorker also have more "processing power"?

Answer (score 11):

A shared worker can work with multiple connections. It posts messages to ports to allow communication between various scripts.

A dedicated worker on the other hand is simply tied to its main connection and cannot post messages to other scripts (workers).

Comment: So, does that mean a regular WebWorker can only have one connection even if the user duplicates their tab running the same script from the same domain? Or is that still considered the same script by the browser? In other words, app.js connects to worker.js, then the user replicates their tab: can tab2 still connect to worker.js? Will worker.js still maintain the same memory pool between tab1's app.js and tab2's app.js. I'm interested because I need to maintain a Queue structure in a background-process / daemon and post events to such daemon from any open tab within the same application.

Comment: I don't understand (although it might be that this answer is almost 8 years old). You can transfer several `MessagePort` objects to a `Worker` and wire up whole networks of connections, Workers communicating with other Workers, iframes, Worklets, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Shared worker allow all front page context script, which call constructor: new SharedWorker("path-to-shared-worker-file.js") to share the same instance of shared worker file running in the background context(another thread of running javascript in the back).

for example, when webpage #1 calling that constructor, if found there is no shared worker loaded up in the back yet, it will cause the background context to download the file and load it up, then later when webpage #2 calling that same constructor(same file path), it found there is an existing shared worker running, it will just using the same one. When worker.port.start() function invoked, it will cause shared worker file onconnect event handler invoked to register caller and obtain the handle to communicate the client port(for postMessage back for example).

However worker, every webpage above will load up one worker file in the background for every single front page, which is not shared the same worker.js instance.