# Can two iframes talk to each other without going through the parent which is in a different domain?

Tags: javascript, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have the following:

page on abc.com

```
<html>
     <iframe src="xyz.com/something"/>
     <iframe src="xyz.com/somethingelse"/>
</html>
```

So as you can imagine abc.com, which I don't control, can't really talk to the iframes on xyz.com and viceversa. I control one of the pages on xyz.com loaded as iframes. Is there a way for me to have the page that I control call functions on the other iframe?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to access `window.parent.frames`? Not sure whether that property is SOP-restricted. If that doesn't work, you could still try a [SharedWorker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778360/whats-the-difference-between-shared-worker-and-worker-in-html5)

Comment: I haven't done extensive testing but it seems like every time I try to access window.parent I get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

They both live on the same domain, why not relay the via server. Maybe via sockets perhaps, so that it would be live. AJAX poll would also work.

Or, you can relay the data through `localStorage` [which triggers storage events](http://html5demos.com/storage-events). Have them both listen for modifications in the data, parse and display accordingly. Not sure about the compatibility on this one. The last time I checked, only Chrome supported storage events.

Comment: Like I said, I only have access to one of the pages on xyz.com/ not both.

Comment: @mntgoat Unless you have control of the other iframed page, then there's no way you can talk to it unless it allows you to. Otherwise, that's a security issue.

Comment: Sure but they are both coming from the same domain, there is no reason other than the parent being from a different domain preventing iframe 1 from calling a javascript function on iframe 2.