# Service Worker vs Shared Worker

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker, service-worker

What is the difference between Service Worker and Shared Worker?

When should I use Service Worker instead of Shared Worker and vice versa?

Comment: Per [specs (draft as of 2015-02-05)](http://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/), a service worker is a type of web worker, which responds to events dispatched from documents and other sources.

Answer (score 31):

A service worker has additional functionality beyond what's available in shared workers, and once registered, they persist outside the lifespan of a given web page.

Service workers can respond to `message` events, like shared workers, but they also have access to additional events. Handling `fetch` events allows service workers to intercept any network traffic (originating from a controlled page) and take specific actions, including serving responses from a `Request`/`Response` cache. There are also [plans](https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/12/15/push-notifications-service-worker) to expose a `push` event to service workers, allowing web apps to receive push messages in the "background".

The other major difference relates to persistence. Once a service worker is registered for a specific origin and scope, it stays registered indefinitely. (A service worker will automatically be updated if the underlying script changes, and it can be either manually or programmatically removed, but that's the exception.) Because a service worker is persistent, and has a life independent of the pages active in a web browser, it opens the door for things like using them to power the aforementioned push messaging—a service worker can be "woken up" and process a `push` event as long as the browser is running, regardless of which pages are active. Future web platform features are likely to take advantage of this persistence as well.

There are other, technical differences, but from a higher-level view, those are what stand out.

Comment: Service Workers have very short life times: ["Developers are advised to keep in mind that service workers may be started and killed many times a second."](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-service-workers-20150205/#motivations).  Though, you might not mean the same thing when you say "lifespan".

Comment: So, web worker lives with page only, while service worker lifecycle is completely separate from page? + service worker has access to cache storage, and special events (like 'fetch'). Any idea why they created **new entity**? Why not just add some special flag to existing web worker, like 'stay alive when page is closed' or something, and add required events and API?

Comment: Service workers are not persistent. They are request handlers - one instance per request/response pair. This allows many concurrent requests and responses without blocking the DOM. Even XHR requests block the DOM in the response. That is because all workers have their own context/event loop.

Comment: @NoahFreitas, Isn't that the same as with sharedworkers?

Comment: @Pacerier the most relevant difference here is the "lifespan" of a sharedworker is established programmatically by the application (via `new SharedWorker` and calling terminate on that worker); whereas for a service worker the browser itself decides how long a worker instance lives and when it begins based on registered event listeners.

Comment: I see this answer is from 5 years ago. is it still up-to-date?

Answer (score 29):

A **SharedWorker** context is a *stateful session* and is designed to multiplex web pages into a single app via asynchronous messaging (client/server paradigm). Its life cycle is *domain based*, rather than *single page based* like **DedicatedWorker** (two-tier paradigm).

A **ServiceWorker** context is designed to be *stateless*. It actually is not a persistent session at all - it is the *inversion of control* (IoC) or event-based *persistence service* paradigm. It serves events, not sessions.

One purpose is to serve concurrent secure asynchronous events for *long running queries* (LRQs) to databases and other *persistence services* (ie clouds). Exactly what a thread pool does in other languages.

For example if your web app executes many concurrent secure LRQs to various cloud services to populate itself, **ServiceWorkers** are what you want. You can execute dozens of secure LRQs instantly, without blocking the user experience. **SharedWorkers** and **DedicatedWorkers** are not easily capable of handling many concurrent secure LRQs. Also, some browsers do not support **SharedWorkers**.

Perhaps they should have called **ServiceWorkers** instead: **CloudWorkers** for clarity, but not all services are clouds.

Hopefully this explanation should lead you to thinking about how the various Worker types were designed to work together. Each has its own specialization, but the common goal is to reduce DOM latency and improve user experience in web based applications.

Throw in some **WebSockets** for streaming and **WebGL** for graphics and you can build some smoking hot web apps that perform like [multiplayer console games](http://www.freefalltournament.com/).

Comment: They should have called `ServiceWorkers` as backgroundworkers

Comment: All workers are background workers - that is their point, to push work off the foreground (DOM) thread.

Answer (score 6):

**2022 06 Update**

WebKit added support for the `SharedWorker` recently, see the details of the resolution in the issue link mentioned below.

**2020 11 Update**

Important detail for anyone interested in this discussion: `SharedWorker` is **NOT** supported by WebKit (was intentionally removed ~v6 or something).

WebKit team are explicitly suggesting to use `ServiceWorker` wherever `SharedWorker` might seem relevant.

For a community wish to get this functionality back to WebKit see [this](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149850) (unresolved as of now) issue.

Comment: Seems to be wrong - MDN docs for SharedWorker do not mention it, and caniuse shows them as supported: https://caniuse.com/?search=SharedWorker

Comment: Well, it was not wrong at the moment of writing, WebKit started supporting it around mid 2022, I'll update the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Adding up to the previous great answers.
As the main difference is that **ServiceWorker** is stateless (will shut down and then start with clear global scope) and **SharedWorker** will maintain state for the duration of the session.

Still there is a possibility to request that **ServiceWorker** will maintain state for the duration of a message handler.

```
s.onmessage = e => e.waitUntil((async () => {
  // do things here
  // for example issue a fetch and store result in IndexedDb
  // ServiceWorker will live till that promise resolves
})())
```

The above code requires that the **ServiceWorker** will not shut down till the promise given as the parameter to *waitUntil* resolves. If many messages are handled concurrently in that manner **ServiceWorker** will not shut down untill all promises are resolved.

This could be possibly used to prolong **ServiceWorker** life indefinitely making it effectively a **SharedWorker**. Still, do keep in mind that browser might decide to force a shut down if **ServiceWorker** goes on fo too long.