# Can SharedWorkers use global variables from other shared workers?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, shared-worker

I need to do some heavy lifting and find it a bit tedious to have to reformat my entire code and was wondering "Can SharedWorkers use global variables from other shared workers?".

If so can someone give a simple demonstration I am fairly new to SharedWorkers. I saw a thread that was very close to answering my question but did not provide a example see:  the second answer with @Raynos

[What's the difference between Shared Worker and Worker in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6778360/8645112)

I also looked at the main documentation and it is a bit lack luster with answering this. It just goes on about using a single shared worker to talk to to other pages .  Anyhow , a example of this in action would be freaking amazing , I've been searching for a long time and come up with nothing thus far .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharedWorkers have [limited support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=sharedworkers) - just Firefox and Chrome. They're probably best avoided unless you have a known audience.

To answer the question: a SharedWorker can **not** directly access variables from another SharedWorker.

The only way to communicate with workers is to post and receive messages. A SharedWorker could initiate another SharedWorker but it would still need to pass the values it wanted to share.

In general, SharedWorkers could be useful where:

1. your application opens multiple windows or frames
2. any instance can set values and initiate processing, and
3. the result would be posted back to some or all instances.

That's a fairly unusual use-case.

Comment: Thanks if I could , I would rate your answer lol :) , just happy to get a response , thanks for taking your time to respond.